# Are there quasiconvex normal subgroups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ by a hyperbolic group, and let $H \lhd G$ be a normal quasiconvex subgroup. Is it possible that $|H| = [G : H] = \infty$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greenberg's theorem for hyperbolic groups, proved by Kapovich and Short, asserts that such an $H$ is finite.

Comment: The proof can be included: if $H$ is quasi-convex of infinite index, then $\partial H$ is a proper closed subset of $\partial G$, and $H$ normal implies that it's $G$-invariant. Since $G$ (which can be supposed non-elementary) is minimal on $\partial G$, this implies $\partial H=\emptyset$, hence $H$ is finite.

Comment: What did Greenberg do?

Comment: @Igor, he did Fuchsian groups.

Comment: But isn't the proof the same in that case?

Comment: Of course. But he did it before hyperbolic groups had been invented, and probably phrased his proof differently. I haven't looked at his paper.

Comment: @Igor: often a particular case of a theorem is harder (say, more tricky) than the general case, because the general statement better isolates the possible ways to find the proof.

Comment: @YCor of course, but I am just curious whether Greenberg's proof is actually different...