# Does any surface of constant curvature admit a cocompact group action?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $S$ is a non-compact and complete surface (2 dimensional smooth Riemannian manifold) of constant curvature. I am wondering if there exists a group $G$ which acts by isometries and properly discontinuously on $S$ such that $S/G$ becomes compact?! Are there maybe any reference where I can find results related to the above situation?

Best wishes

Comment: Such group does not exist quite often.  For example, consider $\mathbb H^2$ - the hyperbolic plane. Suppose $\mathbb Z$ is acting on $\mathbb H^2$ without fixed points (i.e. it is parabolic, or hyperbolic). Then $S=\mathbb H^2/\mathbb Z$ does not admit an action that you would like to have.

Comment: But that does not answer the question. For, on $\mathbb{H}^2$ there are indeed groups acting isometrically and properly discontinuously so that $\mathbb{H}^2/G$ is compact. Any compact, hyperbolic surface arises in this way. The question is asking, given $S$, does there exist a $G$ making $S/G$ compact. So exhibiting a $G$ such that $S/G$ is not compact does not answer the question.

Comment: Most open hyperbolic Riemann surfaces have only trivial automorphism. As isometries = conformal isomorphisms for such surfaces, the answer is no.

Comment: This will happen iff $\pi_1(S)$, seen as a subgroup of the isometry group of $\tilde{S}\simeq \mathbb{H}^2$ (via the deck transformation action), has a discrete cocompact torsion free group which normalizes it. In this case, take $G$ to be the quotient group. Said differently, this is the case iff $\pi_1(S)$ is a normal subgroup in a surface subgroup of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: constant curvature / isometries makes sense in a smooth Riemannian manifold, not in a smooth manifold.

Comment: The paper "*Group actions on nonclosed 2-manifolds*" by McCullough, Miller, and Zimmerman (J. Pure and Applied Algebra, **64**, 3, pp. 269–292) has results such as this:

**Proposition 1.3:** Suppose the group $G$ acts properly discontinuously on the connected $2$-manifold $S$ and that $E$ is the corresponding extension group obtained by lifting the action to the universal cover. Assume that $E$ is not finite. Then $E$ is countably accessible by finite groups if and only if the quotient orbifold $S/G$ is not closed.

Comment: @PaulBryan , I think you've misunderstood aglearner's comment: the surface S without a cocompact action is not the hyperbolic plane, but the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by the action of the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: @HJRW yes you are right. In my defense, I had just got back from the pub :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Uri Bader says in the comments, covering-space theory implies that this happens if and only if $\pi_1S$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is some compact surface.

The cases of positive and zero curvature are easy, so we may as well assume that $S$ and $\Sigma$ are of constant negative curvature.  In this case, a theorem of Greenberg places strong restrictions on normal subgroups of surface groups.

> **Theorem (Greenberg):** If $H$ is a finitely generated, normal subgroup of the fundamental group of a hyperbolic surface $\Sigma$, then $H$ is either trivial or of finite index

In particular, if $S$ is non-compact but not the hyperbolic plane, and $\pi_1S$ is finitely generated, then $S$ does not admit such a group action.

Comment: Greenberg's theorem is apparently contained in [[1960](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=115130)]. Or more directly Karass-Solitar [[1973](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=320152)], in the form: "Fuchsian groups have the f.g.n. property".

Comment: In fact, the proof of the theorem is very short: see YCor's comment on the answer to this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193369/are-there-quasiconvex-normal-subgroups .

Comment: Very *kapovich* short!